# Wordpress query_posts to modify wp_query

Tags: wordpress

When I alter main `$wp_query` with `query_posts` function, all my conditional tags are false and all pages have `[is_home] => 1`.

So all custom templates I made by modifying main query to save some time are now `home`. Anyone knows a fix for this?

Comment: You shouldn't be using that function to modify the loop. Use WP_Query instead or the `pre_get_posts` hook.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to create custom queries. `query_posts` breaks the main query, as you have seen. Whether or not to use a custom query for your specific needs, I don't know.

I have done a complete post about this subject on WPSE that you can go and check [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545). Also go and check out [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) in the codex